# Is 4x7+dp LED segment display wired the same as 4x8 LED dot matrix?

Tags: led-driver, 7segmentdisplay, dot-matrix-display

I'm currently working on a project that need a 4x7+dp common cathode LED segments display.

I have found two drivers for it that I like.

#1 https://www.issi.com/WW/pdf/31FL3731.pdf

#2 https://ams.com/documents/20143/36005/AS1115_DS000206_1-00.pdf/e040d791-18f8-9f29-01f9-927bf6336bb7

Edit: Here is a link for the vintage 4x7+dp segment display:
https://www.keesvandersanden.nl/calculators/datasheets/HP_50827400.pdf

I was wondering if a dot matrix led display is actually wired the same as a standard 7 segment led display. As far as I can see they are but I can't really wrap my head around it. I'm asking because it influences whatever I actually have a choice between chip #1 and #2.

Side note: I know that some drivers have bdc/hex decoders build in but I don't need them. All I need is to turn select leds on or off as I'm doing the rendering on the MCU.

I also know that I could do without a driver and use resistors and FETs or IO expanders but i'm low on pins and have very limited board space.

I'm looking forward to your responses.

Comment: Do you have links to part numbers for the displays?

Comment: I have added a link to the display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the 7-segment array is matrixed like a typical the led array

so you can use either of those drivers.

Comment: Thank you, i'll go for the AS1115 then. But I guess I have to research what is col and what is row on that chip.